Zeros of a function defined on $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^2$
Let $u$ be a smooth function on the sphere, and for each $y \in \mathbb{S}^2$, let $R_y$ be the $180^\circ$ rotation about the vector $y$. For each pair $(x, y) \in \mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^2$, define the function
$$
f(x, y) = \left(u(x) - u(R_y(x)), \nabla u(x) - R_y(\nabla u(R_y(x)))\right).
$$
As noted by Pietro Majer in the comments, $R_y(x)=2(x.y)y-x$.
I am interested in determining whether there exist points $x, y \in \mathbb{S}^2$ with $y\neq \pm x$ such that $f(x, y) = 0$. Essentially, this inquiry seeks pairs of distinct points $x_1 = x$ and $x_2 = R_y(x)$ where the function $u$ takes the same value and the gradients at these points are equal, modulo the rotation that maps $x_1$ to $x_2$.
Define $f: \mathbb{S}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$f(x)=\left(u(x)-u(-x), |\nabla u(x)|-|\nabla u(-x)|\right).$$
Then it follows from Borsuk–Ulam theorem that there exists $x_0$ where $f$ vanishes. So one can always find two distinct points where the norm of the gradient are equal. Noe also that at the antipodal points, the gradients are both also orthogonal to $x$. By relaxing the constraint in the above sense and not requiring the two points to be antipodal, I am looking for two points whose gradients  as well as the values are equal in the above sense.
There is a generalization of Borsuk–Ulam theorem to product spaces, but it does not seem to apply: file:///Users/new-imachome/Downloads/1475179848%20(2).pdf
More generally, I am looking for a rotation such that the function $v(x)=u(x)-u(R(x))$ and $\nabla v(x)$ vanishes at two distinct points on the sphere. $R$ could be any rotation, and not necessarily a $180$ degree rotation about a vector. Note that when the rotation is a 180 degrees rotation, then if function $v(x)=u(x)-u(Rx)$ vanishes at $x_0$, then it also vanishes at $Rx_0\neq x_0$, and we automatically get two points where $v$ and it's gradient vanishes.

Isnt $R_{-y}=R_y$ and thus we get that $f(x,-x)=f(x,x)=0$? Maybe you wanted to exclude that case as well ?

@HenrikRüping Yes, I revised the question. Thank you.

Isn’t $R_y$ involutory so that $R^{-1}_y=R_y$? I understand  that $R_y(x)=2(x\cdot y)y-x$ for  $x,y$ in $\mathbb S^2$, is this correct?

@PietroMajer Yes, $R_y$ is involutory. Your formula for $R_y(x)$ is correct. I will include it in the body of the question.

As for the last line, in the antipodal case, do we want the gradients to be the same or opposite? Like if $u(\mathbf{x})$ is always the same as $u(-\mathbf{x})$, don't we get $\nabla u(-\mathbf{x})=-\nabla u(\mathbf{x})$?

@KhashF You are right. I revised the question.

Maybe I am missing something, but  $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}$ yields $R_{\mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}$. In that case $R_{\mathbf{y}}(\nabla u(R_{\mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{x})))=R_{\mathbf{x}}(\nabla u(\mathbf{x}))$ which is equal to $-\nabla u(\mathbf{x})$ since $\nabla u(\mathbf{x})\perp\mathbf{x}$.  Thus I think $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x})=0$ does not hold unless you change the second component of $f$ to $\nabla u(\mathbf{x})+R_{\mathbf{y}}(\nabla u(R_{\mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{x})))$.

@KhashF You are right, $f(x,x)$ or $f(x,-x)$ could be zero only if $\nabla u(x)=0$. I revised the question.

@MathLearner So you are set on the second component of $f$ being what it is? Because if the minus sign is changed to plus, then $f$ vanishes when $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}$, and then there may be a chance to tackle the problem with the implicit function theorem. But if you really want the minus sign in the second component, then nevermind.

@KhashF Yes, indeed I am looking for a rotation such that the function $v(x)=u(x)-u(R(x))$ and $\nabla v$ vanishes at two distinct points on the sphere. $R$ could be any rotation, and not necessarily a $180$ degree rotation about a vector.

In the last question (with any rotation $R$) do you really mean  $v$ and $\nabla v$ vanish at 2 distinct points $x_1$ and $x_2$? (so  possibly $x_2\neq Rx_1$,  $u(x_1)=u(Rx_1)\neq u(x_2)$)

Also note that, especially if you already received an answer, you may want to post a further variation of the question as a separate post.

@PietroMajer Yes, I want $v$ to vanish at two distinct points. I have not received the answer I am looking for, provided solutions answers the problem under additional assumptions which makes the question a completely different question.

Interesting question.

12th version of this question.

Now that I have a better understanding of what the question entails, I am going reorganize my answer. We are interested in points where a function of form $v(\mathbf{x}):=u(\mathbf{x})-u(R\mathbf{x})$--here $R\in{\rm{SO}}(3)$ denotes a rotation--and its gradient vanish simultaneously; i.e. points $\mathbf{x}_0\in\Bbb{S}^2$ with $u(\mathbf{x}_0)=u(R\mathbf{x}_0)$  and
$\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_0)-R^{\rm{T}}\nabla u(R\mathbf{x}_0)=\mathbf{0}\Leftrightarrow 
R\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_0)=\nabla u(R\mathbf{x}_0)$. Of course, certain trivial cases should be excluded, like $R$ being the identity or more generally, cases where $R\mathbf{x}_0=\mathbf{x}_0$ is allowed: Otherwise, one can take $\mathbf{x}_0$ to be a critical point and any rotation fixing the unit vector $\mathbf{x}_0$ works. Hence I am going to focus on cases where $R\mathbf{x}_0\neq\mathbf{x}_0$. The question is if there exists $R\in{\rm{SO}}(3)$ and two distinct points on the sphere for which these equations hold.

Question) Are there two distinct points $\mathbf{x}_0,\mathbf{x}_1\in\Bbb{S}^2$ and a rotation $R\in{\rm{SO}(3)}$ such that $R\mathbf{x}_i\neq\mathbf{x}_i$, $u(\mathbf{x}_i)=u(R\mathbf{x}_i)$  and
$R\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_i)=\nabla u(R\mathbf{x}_i)$ for $i\in\{0,1\}$?

I am going to prove the existence of one such point, and discuss how the same idea can potentially be applied to the general question. But before that, a remark regarding the special case of $180^\circ$-rotations $R=R_{\mathbf{y}}$ which are mentioned at the beginning of the question: If $R=R_{\mathbf{y}}$, since this is an involution, once we find one desired point $\mathbf{x}_0$, $R_{\mathbf{y}}\mathbf{x}_0$ would work as $\mathbf{x}_1$. Notice that $R_{\mathbf{y}}\mathbf{x}_0\neq\mathbf{x}_0$ amounts to $\mathbf{y}\neq\pm\mathbf{x}_0$ (such a condition also appears at the beginning of the question). An even more special case is when $R(\mathbf{x})=-\mathbf{x}$. I am going to say a few words about the antipodal case at the end.

Claim) There exist $R\in{\rm{SO}}(3)$ and $\mathbf{x}_0\in\Bbb{S}^2$ such that $R\mathbf{x}_0\neq\mathbf{x}_0$,
$u(\mathbf{x}_0)=u(R\mathbf{x}_0)$  and  $R\nabla
u(\mathbf{x}_0)=\nabla u(R\mathbf{x}_0)$.

Proof of the Claim)  Let $C$ be a connected component of a regular fiber of $u:\Bbb{S}^2\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$. Thus $C$ is homeomorphic to a circle. We deduce that the function $|\nabla u|:C\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ cannot be injective. So there exist points $\mathbf{x}_0\neq\mathbf{x}_1$ on $C$ with  $|\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_0)|=|\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_1)|>0$. And of course $u(\mathbf{x}_0)=u(\mathbf{x}_1)$ since these points belong to the same level set. Now, given that we are dealing with the gradient of a function defined on the unit sphere, we have the following pairs of orthogonal unit vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$:
$$
\mathbf{x}_0\perp \frac{\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_0)}{|\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_0)|}, \quad \mathbf{x}_1\perp \frac{\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_1)}{|\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_1)|}.
$$
Hence there exists a unique element $R$ of ${\rm{SO}}(3)$ with $R(\mathbf{x}_0)=\mathbf{x}_1$ and
$R\left(\frac{\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_0)}{|\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_0)|}\right)=\frac{\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_1)}{|\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_1)|}$. The latter equality can be written as  $R\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_0)=\nabla u(R\mathbf{x}_0)$ because
$|\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_0)|=|\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_1)|$.
The partial solution above allows us to reformulate the question, at least for regular points of $u$, as:

Question$^\prime$) Let $$ \mathbf{M}:=\{(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})\in\Bbb{S}^2\times\Bbb{S}^2\mid\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{y},u(\mathbf{x})=u(\mathbf{y}),|\nabla
 u(\mathbf{x})|=|\nabla u(\mathbf{y})|>0\}; $$ and define
$F:\mathbf{M}\rightarrow{\rm{SO}}(3)$ by setting
$F(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ to be the unique element of ${\rm{SO}}(3)$
under which $\mathbf{x}\mapsto\mathbf{y}$,  $\nabla
u(\mathbf{x})\mapsto\nabla u(\mathbf{y})$ and  $\mathbf{x}\times\nabla
u(\mathbf{x})\mapsto\mathbf{y}\times\nabla u(\mathbf{y})$. Is $F$
non-injective?

(Keep in mind that if two distinct pairs $(\mathbf{x}_0,\mathbf{y}_0)$ and $(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{y}_1)$ belong to the same fiber $F^{-1}(R)$, then, as desired, $R\mathbf{x}_i\neq\mathbf{x}_i$, $u(\mathbf{x}_i)=u(R\mathbf{x}_i)$  and
$R\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_i)=\nabla u(R\mathbf{x}_i)$ for $i\in\{0,1\}$ where $\mathbf{x}_0\neq\mathbf{x}_1$. Also notice that $F(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x})=F(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})^{-1}$, thus it is also enough to show that the range of $F$ contains an involution.)
Given that the subset $\mathbf{M}$ of $\Bbb{S}^2\times\Bbb{S}^2$ is defined by two constraints, it should generically be a 2D "object" (except in special cases like $u$ being constant). So I struggle to see any immediate argument showing that the map $F$ from $\mathbf{M}$ to the 3D group ${\rm{SO}}(3)$ cannot be injective.
The antipodal case) It is possible to find antipodal points belonging to same level set whose gradient vectors have the same projection along a given direction.
To see this, it suffices to apply the Borsuk–Ulam  to
$$
\mathbf{x}\in \Bbb{S}^2\mapsto \left(u(\mathbf{x}),\langle\nabla u(\mathbf{x}),\mathbf{p}\rangle\right)\in\Bbb{R}^2.
$$
where $\mathbf{p}\in\Bbb{S}^2\subset\Bbb{R}^3$ is an arbitrary unit vector. The theorem implies the existence of  $\mathbf{x}_0\in\Bbb{S}^2$ for which $u(\mathbf{x}_0)=u(-\mathbf{x}_0)$ and moreover,
the projections of
$\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_0),\nabla u(-\mathbf{x}_0)\in\Bbb{R}^3$
along the line parallel to $\mathbf{p}$ passing through the origin coincide.
A bit more can be said in view of the fact that $\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_0),\nabla u(-\mathbf{x}_0)$ both belong to the subspace
${\rm{T}}_{\mathbf{x}_0}\,\Bbb{S}^2={\rm{T}}_{-\mathbf{x}_0}\,\Bbb{S}^2$
which is the orthogonal complement of $\mathbf{x_0}$ in $\Bbb{R}^3$. For instance, if $\mathbf{p}$ is so that $u(\mathbf{p})\neq u(-\mathbf{p})$, then the unit vectors $\mathbf{x}_0,\mathbf{p},-\mathbf{p}$ are distinct. Hence vectors $\nabla u(\mathbf{x}_0),\nabla u(-\mathbf{x}_0)$ are subjected to two independent constraints: they are orthogonal to $\mathbf{x}_0$ and have the same projection along $\mathbf{p}$; thus they differ by a multiple of $\mathbf{p}\times\mathbf{x_0}$.

Thank you KhashF, but this is not what I want.

Thank you KashF, but the problem asks for a rotation $$
such that $=()−u()$ and its gradient vanishes at two distinct points. In your proof it is only guaranteed to vanish in one point.

@MathLearner Your question was changed multiple times so a bit hard to keep track. Initially, you asked for $u(\mathbf{x})=u(R_{\mathbf{y}}\mathbf{x})$ and $\nabla u(\mathbf{x})=R_{\mathbf{y}}\nabla u(R_{\mathbf{y}}\mathbf{x})$ where $\mathbf{y}\neq\pm\mathbf{x}$ to exclude the trivial case of $R_{\mathbf{y}}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}$. Then you said $R_{\mathbf{y}}$ is allowed to be any rotation. Rewriting for a general rotation, the goal is: $u(\mathbf{x})=u(R\mathbf{x})$ and $\nabla u(\mathbf{x})=R^{\rm{T}}\nabla u(R\mathbf{x})$. Meaning a single common zero of $v,\nabla v$, not two.

@KashF, The question never changed. I just added extra details. The part that I asked for a function $v$ with two points has never changed, probably you did not pay attention. The point is that of the rotation is 180 degrees, then we will automatically get two points with such properties. Indeed $v=u(x)-u(Rx)$ would vanish both at $x_0$ and $R(x_0)$. The rotation does not need to have 180 degrees, but I still want two points. This has never changes in my writing.

I made the two bold in the body so people pay more attention.

Thank you anyways. If I don't get any other response, I will accept your answer.
